# How to get a specific item in a array of objects in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So, I need to get a specific item from an array of objects in Laravel.

First, I make this selection here:

```
public function example($userId)
{
    $type = DB::table('users_type')
                     ->select('type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c')
                     ->where(function ($query) use ($userId)
                     {
                         $query->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
                     })
                     ->get();
    return $type;
}
```

Ok, I have all records in an array of objects with (`type_a`, `type_b`, `type_c`), that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "type_a": 0,
        "type_b": 0,
        "type_c": 0
    },
    {
        "type_a": 1,
        "type_b": 1,
        "type_c": 1
    },
    {
        "type_a": 1,
        "type_b": 0,
        "type_c": 1
    },
]
```

I made this code in my controller:

```
//calling the function example
$type_ticket = example($user_id);

//get the types from the first register from the array 
//of objects that I returned from the function example
$type_a = $type_ticket[0]->type_a;
$type_b = $type_ticket[0]->type_b;
$type_c = $type_ticket[0]->type_c;
```

Now, I need to get just 1 of this tuple. 
For example, the one where (`type_a = 1`, `type_b = 0`, `type_c = 1`).

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to get values of your *types*?

Comment: So, why not write the code for that specific requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array and compare against an array_value of the subarray.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $sub){
    if(array_values($sub) == [1,0,1]){
        $res[$key] = $sub;
    }
}
var_dump($res);
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["type_a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["type_b"]=>
    int(0)
    ["type_c"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1dtNZ

Answer (score 0):

You can try use collections https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-where

something like:

```
//calling the function example
$type_ticket = example($user_id)->where('type_a', 1)->where('type_b', 0)->where('type_c', 1);
```

also your function can be simplified slightly by

```
public function example($userId)
{
    return DB::table('users_type')
                     ->select('type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c')
                     ->whereUserId($userId)
                     ->get();
}
```